# 'IN ALL' clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

```
public class ReduceResult
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample Records:**

```
UserName        Text
UsernameA       Text1, Text2, Text3 
UsernameB       Text2, Text3, Text4
UsernameC       Text1, Text2, Text3
```

I require users that include ALL of the text mentioned in the where clause. For example

If the where clause includes Text IN `{ Text1, Text2, Text3 }`, I should get records of  User `'A'` and `'C'` since ALL the required text are included in their records.
I should not get User `'B'` records as `'Text1'` is absent in his records. I need to achieve it using `LINQ` .Can you please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
string[] texts = new string[]{"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"};
var records = from x in list
              let a = from b in x.Text.Split(',') select b.Trim()
              where a.Intersect(texts).Count() == texts.Count()
              select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the ReduceResult class, then you can implement IEquatable and add Equals method and override GetHashCode().
Like this:

```
public class ReduceResult: IEquatable<ReduceResult>
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ReduceResult other)
    {

    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

    }   
}
```

You can then compare the two ReduceResult like any other primary types like int, string.
eg, ReduceResult1 == ReduceResult2

If not, then you can create a Comparer class:

```
class ReduceResultComparer : IEqualityComparer<ReduceResult>
{
    public bool Equals(ReduceResult x, ReduceResult y)
    {

    }

    public int GetHashCode(ReduceResult reduceresult)
    {

    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
    //This outside your linq query
    var comparer = new ReduceResultComparer(); 

    //This inside query
    comparer.Equals(ReduceResult1, ReduceResult2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you question correctly it is just a regular where clause like this.

```
var data = from x in listOfObjects
                   where x.Text == "Text1, Text2, Text3"
                   select new ReduceResult
                   {
                       UserName = x.UserName,
                       ProfileImageUrl = x.ProfileImageUrl,
                       Text = x.Text,
                   };
```